# Haskell - How to take n items from a tuple list after sorting

Tags: list, haskell, take

Hi I am a beginner to haskell. I am trying to get the first 3 items from this tuple list:

```
[("and",2),("cat",1),("dog",1),("rabbit",1),("the",2)]
```

First I sort the list by frequency and descending order:

```
sortWords =  sortBy(flip compare `on` snd)
```

This gives me the result:

```
[("and",2),("the",2),("cat",1),("dog",1),("rabbit",1)]
```

Then I know I can do the function:

```
take 3 [("and",2),("the",2),("cat",1),("dog",1),("rabbit",1)]
```

which gives me the **desired** result of `[("and",2),("the",2),("cat",1)]`

However, I want to be able to incorporate the `take` function into the `sortWords` function. The problem is, when I attempt to do this, for example:

```
sortWords =  take 3 (sortBy(flip compare `on` snd))
```

this does not work.

Ideally, I want to keep `sortWords` as the end function so I do not want to pass it into another to be able to perform the `take` function. If there's a way to perform `take` before calling `sortWords` that could be a solution, however I have also tried this and found that the words which are taken are not sorted first and therefore do not give me the result I want.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that `` sortBy (flip compare `on` snd) `` is **not** a list of tuples, it is a function that takes as input a list of tuples and returns a list of tuples.

We can use the **function composition operator [`(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.)**:

```
sortWords :: Ord b => [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
sortWords = take 3 . sortBy (flip compare `on` snd)
```

here we thus first will apply `` sortBy (flip compare `on` snd) `` on the input, and then we will apply `take 3` on the output of that function.